# How can I do an if condition in PHP with multiple conditions?

Tags: php

I have 4 variables.

How can I do the following?

```
$x1='on';
$x2='';
$x3='';
$x4='';

if $x1=='on' and $x2 is empty and $x3 is empty and $x4 is empty , do this else do that ?
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
if($x =='on' && $x2 =="" && $x3 == "" && $x4 == ""){

}else{

}
```

For future references PHP manual and here's link to expressive operators:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use the empty command, like so:

```
if($x =='on' && empty($x2) && empty($x3) && empty($x4)){

}
else{

}
```

Comment: You [shouldn't use `empty` for variables which should exist](http://kunststube.net/isset); use `!$x2` instead.